# How to add ScrollBar inside ZK Chosenbox Component?

Tags: java, scrollbar, zk

I am using **ZK Chosenbox** for multiple selection ,issue with  **ZK Chosenbox** Component is that if i selected 4-5 items its increasing the size(Height or width)  of the its own so its looking ugly because overriding other components in the page rather than i will want to show **scrollbar** inside the **ZK Chosenbox **.
[image: Before Selection of items]

[image: After Selection of items]

You can see in second image its overlap the another components.Can any way to use Scrolling in **ZK Chosenbox**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override  [`overflow`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) or `overflow-y` if you just want the vertical scrollbar in `.z-chosenbox` or the element
to `scroll` or `auto`.

```
<chosenbox ... style="overflow:scroll">
```

or

```
<style>
 .z-chosenbox {
      overflow:scroll
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks ..One more question it is possible to use SelectOption with ChosenBox?